# How do I format currency in Vega-Lite?

Tags: data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to format values as currency in the Vega-Lite editor. I'm attempting to copy the docs but I'm getting a weird error. The Y axis is a numerical value. Passing in a formatting string gives "value expected".

Here's the json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Protocol Chart",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 225,
  "data": {
        "values": [
        {
            "asset": "eth",
            "time": "2021-06-15T00:00:00Z",
            "ReferenceRateUSD": "2577.04473863238"
        },
        {
            "asset": "eth",
            "time": "2021-06-16T00:00:00Z",
            "ReferenceRateUSD": "2552.74103641146"
        },
        {
            "asset": "eth",
            "time": "2021-06-17T00:00:00Z",
            "ReferenceRateUSD": "2360.99938690824"
        }
    ]
  },
  "config": {
        "view": {
            "stroke": "transparent"
        }
  },
  "mark": "line",
    "encoding": {
        "x": {
            "axis": {
                "domainColor": "#DDD",
                "grid": false, 
                "labelColor": "#AEAEAE", 
                "ticks": false, 
                "labelPadding": 10
            }, 
            "field": "time", 
            "type": "temporal", 
            "title": ""
        },
        "y": {
            "axis": {
                "labelOffset": 2,
                "domainColor": "white",
                "labelColor": "#AEAEAE", 
                "ticks": false, 
                "labelPadding": 10,
                "format": '$.2f'
            }, 
            "field": "ReferenceRateUSD", 
            "type": "quantitative", 
            "title": "", 
            "scale": {
                "zero": false
            }
        },
        "color": {
            "field": "doesntmatter", 
            "type": "nominal", 
            "legend": null,
            "scale": {
                "range": ["#91DB97"]
            }
        }
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? How do I get it to accept my formatting string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$.2f"` looks like a the correct [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format) string for currency, but note that this is only valid if the associated `formatType` is `"number"` (see [axis label docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#labels)).

Since you did not include a full [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're seeing, I can only venture a guess that your data type is not numeric, and this is why the formatting is failing. If that's not the case, I'd suggest editing your question to provide a complete example of the error you're seeing.

---

Edit: your full example appears to work correctly with the current version of vega/vega-lite ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AAV1bTGyhtBAAgDCMJOsyKQAdxrL6aMQAZPS+DTJYaABMQWJKykiYKKigxEiCDGpoANqgSBAQcA7oWTCOOghwaCBBnkEAjPyeAGz85WIAKt6ozd4AWo4ASnAAZnDqcLJQcJ2RcACqAMoAIsWhAOzzlJ4ALCvzAMwAHNUbQdsgAL4KaRlZxbn5NIVzZZU1ddVNni0v7V29-YPDo5gTM3MxGIgpR5ityp4NtVweUVtUjicQOlMtkQJclAUiuhShUqrVyvNnq9Xh0lN0+gMhiMxlNZtioZ5KABOFnbapMzxbIIrI4AXWOIDMsh6-jQsRocCcYpAEEwRgA1liQHKkLIIDg7IMHIcBch1PLisJZEUlN82MoaLIyNKAB7SpA2mgQaXKNjIS1WcxsdTFADE0wDjjImmUaB68UySkESCYcEEnsE3r9AEEAKJptNXKDy52ocOCSMgaOxwT6JDKC1WtAQgUiuOh9CY-IATxwSr+CBw3viV0wgiVCJAzftjtzoGLcYA8j0eijguE3UgPV6fegnDARI4J-GVyn0-uszmwxG4FGY3GyxXLdbUBClD1vchUWBKEEeoO64IGyByV8qb9-lmDFWyVABHBhVR0KIdFIXt+2KRxoHiLFQAAL36NhjwLOAdSUMxE1XUBP2-V01FkTAnz+H1gLbYpZDdS0eyjchBgbWQGEEQQlCQ+CYhAdRVTILFkhAX0mXKaYACEmXmEB+R1Q4gA)):

[image]

Perhaps you need to update your vega/vega-lite libraries?

Comment: I updated it. The data itself is numerical and of the four options I saw quantitative seemed the most correct but I must be in error...

Comment: Thanks - see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what the problem was. The version with all the data points (not just the three) breaks the editor but it turns out to work in my code so no worries.